# Hensel's lemma & $p$-adic polynomial roots

Tags: p-adic-number-theory, hensels-lemma

I want to determine the number of roots of $f(X) = X^3-5X+20$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ using Hensel's lemma (lemma is on the bottom). Unfortunately I am not very well trained to solve this. Take for example $p=2$. Then reducing the polynomial modulo 2 we get
\begin{align*}
f(X) &= X^3 - 5X+20 \equiv 0 \mod 2 \\
f'(X) &= 3X^2-5\equiv X + 1 \mod 2
\end{align*} 
That would mean that only $0\in\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ gives a solution such that $f(0) \equiv 0$ and $f'(0)\not \equiv 0$ modulo 2, which then by Hensel's lemma gives a unique root of $f$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2$, which is $0$ modulo $2$.

The problem is that I don't know the relation between finding a root via Hensel's lemma and there really being one. I have found one root via Hensel's lemma, but what guarantees me there aren't more?

Any help on how to proceed is most welcome. Thank you in advance.

---

The lemma I am using:

Let $K$ be a complete field with discrete valuation $v$, valuation ring $O$ and residue field $k$. Let $f(X)\in O(X)$. Suppose that the reduction $\bar{f}(X)\in k[X]$ has a simple root $\bar{a}$, ie $\bar{f}(\bar{a}) = 0$ and $\bar{f}'(\bar{a})\neq0$. Then there exists a unique $x\in O$ such that $f(x) = 0$ and $\bar{x}=\bar{a}$.

Comment: Are you lifting roots mod $p$ to roots mod powers of $p$?  That's what Hensel's Lemma is about. There are $2$ roots mod $2$, by inspection.

Comment: I added the lemma as I learned it. Could you explain how you determined there are two roots?

Comment: Plugged in.  But that may be because my meaning for $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is different from yours.

Comment: Ah my communication is so off.... I meant the $2$-adic number field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This polynomial has a double root at $1$ in $\mathbb{F}_2$, so the out of the box Hensel's lemma won't apply.  However we can still apply a modified version by going one power of two up. In particular the double root at 1 splits into two simple roots mod 4 (at 1 and 3).  Now a modified Hensel's lemma (with essentially the same proof as the usual version) gives us that these each have a unique 2-adic lift.

One thing that is different about this modified Hensel's lemma from what you are used to is that if we want to solve $f(x) \equiv 0 \bmod 2^n$, the lifts we get will only be unique mod $2^{n-1}$.  In particular we get that $f(x) \equiv 0 \bmod 2^n$ has 5 solutions for all $n > 2$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I looked at the proof and was able to adjust the assumption to powers of $2$. One more question, is there a way to see whether a root splits in different ones in a higher power? Take $p=5$ for example. Then $f$ has a triple root at zero modulo 5, which (I believe) are no roots anymore when we look modulo 25. It would be exhausting (and impossible) to check all powers. Thank you.

Comment: I think the strategy is to increase the prime power one step at a time. If you ever have a root such that the derivative does not vanish then it automatically lifts to all higher powers by this modified Hensel's lemma.  If you reach a power such that there are no solutions lifting the one you are looking at then there are no p-adic solutions.  One thing to potentially be worried about is maybe you keep going up a prime power finding lifts but having the derivatives keep vanishing, but I think one can show that implies the polynomial has a double root.

Comment: For $p=5$, Eisenstein applies, since all coeffs are divisible by $5$ and the constant is not divisible by $25$. So irreducible, no roots in $\Bbb Z_5$.

Answer (score 3):

Just for the number of roots in the $2$-adic integers $\Bbb Z_2$, I recommend forming $g(X)=f(X+5)=X^3+15X^2+70X+120$. Then I use something rather more powerful than plain old Hensel, namely the Newton polygon, in which you plot $(n,v_2(a_n))$ for every monomial $a_nX^n$ in your polynomial. The points you plot then are $(0,3)$, $(1,1)$, $(2,0)$, and $(3,0)$. You then take the “upper convex hull” of these points, which has segments of slope $-2$, $-1$, and $0$, each of width $1$. This says that in $\Bbb Z_2$, there are roots of $2$-adic valuation $2$, $1$, and $0$, three in all. You may be able to take $g$ and find the roots directly with your form of Hensel.